# Open Socket fails if executable is on a network share

Tags: windows-7, winsock

We have the problem that we are not able to open a socket, if the executable is on a network share:
errortext we get:

> 0.0.0.0:2220: In TcpipSocket::TcpipSocket: Invalid argument.
>   Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level 
>   to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current 
>   state of the socket-for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not 
>   listening.

The real adress should be 127.0.0.1.
the program works fine if the exe lies on my local HDD

I'm suspecting "security" related reason, Like MS doesn't allow opening sockets from network shares
or something similar.
Somebody has some clue?

The program is written in C++ using Win32api

Comment: I updated the posting,
We are using C++ and Win32 Api (or at least Winsock)

Comment: Still no code for `class TcipSocket` shown. But we'd really like a stripped down program with just `main`, and still showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the MSDN Forum
If you are interested, details can be found here
[social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3076a9cd-57a0-418d-8de1-07adc3b486bb/socket-fails-with-error-10022-when-application-is-run-from-certain-network-shares-on-vista-and?forum=wsk)